# How to enable gravity in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

i have a ball which i have to drop from a height and it should behave as it behave in the real world mean it should drop with g=9.8 and also bounce back.can any one tell me how i can do it in open gl in c++?

Comment: OpenGL is a low level graphics API, not a fully fledged physics, game, or even graphics engine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OpenGL is only for drawing 3D graphics, it knows nothing of concepts like speed, mass, velocity, time, acceleration and gravity (or rhubarb pie calorie count, for that matter).

You need a physics engine, or a simple physics simulation:

The simple per-frame loop goes something like this:

- dt = time_now - time_prev_frame
- acc = -9.8
- vel += acc * dt
- pos += vel * dt
- draw object at pos

That being said, there are people who implement particle systems using OpenGL GPUs for simulation, but then adapt the graphics concepts, primitives & calculations to compute positions and velocities by implementing the physics equations themselves..

Answer (score 6):

OpenGL is not a game engine. OpenGL just draws stuff to the screen. And the stuff it draws are triangles. They way how it draws this stuff is determined by parameters like lighting and textures and may be fine tuned by shaders, but that's about it.

You want a game engine.

Answer (score 5):

It's been a little while since I've done OpenGL programming, but last I saw, there was no "enable gravity" feature.

The exact behavior of "as it behave in the real world" (sic) is highly underspecified.  What's the material?  What's the temperature?  What's the shape?  And so on.

You might want to start by reading the [Physics Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_engine) wikipedia article.